# Is it possible to create an incremental snapshot file from an existing tar archive?

Tags: backup, tar

I have created a large tar archive and am now looking to do an incremental backup. The [documentation](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/tar/) indicates that a snapshot file can only be created when the initial tar backup file is created.

Is it possible to list the contents of an existing tar archive to create a file in the [snapshot file format](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Snapshot-Files.html)?

Is there enough detail in the original tar archive to allow an incremental backup to work correctly? (assuming some info such as inode numbers are fudged)

Comment: GNU tar is known to be unable to do incremental restores. Do you really like to make your backups to rely on this program?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the amount of fudging you're willing to do.

Let's use format 1 for a moment. It's a list only of the directories in the tarball.

The fields relevant to each entry in the list tarball are: mtime(seconds+nsecs), device, inode.

In later incremental passes, if the device/inode fields no longer match, or if the mtime has moved backwards, ALL the files in the directory will be added to the incremental tarball. If the device/inode match, and mtime is the same or greater, it will pick up all new files greater than or equal to the mtime (The equal-to part matters for filesystems with low mtime resolution, otherwise files might be skipped).

Format 2 extended this via the Dumpdir format, which complicates it,
 mostly adding cases where files aren't backed up as they came with an older mtime.

So, given a tarball, is it possible to recreate a snapshot file? Yes, but it's messy, and you'll probably miss some files. There is `--no-check-device` which skips the device check, but the directory inodes are the big risk.